# unity-networking: prefabs not being seen outside of client on server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'm trying to make players create shurikens, however they only appear on the client that they were made by. I've added a network identity to the shuriken prefab, and added the shuriken prefab to registered spawnable prefabs in the network manager. Below is the following command in the player script for creating the shuriken prefabs:

```
    void CmdThrowShuriken(){
    //creates knife
    shurikenCount -= 1;
    myAnimator.SetTrigger("throw");
    if (shurikenCount != 0) {
        if (facingRight) {
            GameObject tmp = (GameObject)Instantiate (knifePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            NetworkServer.Spawn(tmp);
            tmp.GetComponent<Shuriken> ().Initialize (Vector2.left);
        } else {
            GameObject tmp = (GameObject)Instantiate (knifePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            NetworkServer.Spawn(tmp);
            tmp.GetComponent<Shuriken> ().Initialize (Vector2.right);
        }
    }
}
```

And the shuriken script:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
public class Shuriken_net : NetworkBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
private float speed = 10;

private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

private Vector2 direction;

void Start () {
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate(){

}
void RotateRight () {
    transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward * 45);
}
public void Initialize(Vector2 direction){
    this.direction = direction;
}
[ServerCallback]
void Update () {
    myRigidbody.velocity = direction * speed;
    RotateRight ();
}
void OnCollisionEneter(Collision other){
    if (PlayerNet.Instance.health != 0) {
        PlayerNet.Instance.health -= 5;
    }
    if (!isServer) {
        return;
    }
    if (other.gameObject.tag != "Ninja") {
        return;
    }
    if (PlayerNet.Instance.health != null) {
        PlayerNet.Instance.TakeDamage(5);
    }
}
void OnBecameInvisible(){
    NetworkServer.Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

}

Comment: I'm rusty with this API, but does the object have a NetworkIdentity component? Is the prefab registered on both clients? Also, setting up the variables manually on the client like you are is a little wonky unless you're spawning with client authority (telling the server that one client will be controlling that object). Normally the data is set by server commands. If you set it in a client without authority, it may not be synced.

Comment: Yes, i have added a NetworkIdentity to the shuriken, sorry for lack of detail, and the player prefab is in the network manager and I did add the shuriken prefab as a registered spawnable prefab, I assume that this gives the player authority to spawn the shurikens, however you raise a good point, and I will have to try spawning the player with client authority. Thank you for the response

Comment: I meant spawing the shuriken with client authority. But you shouldn't need to. I found the Unity multiplayer tutorial really helpful when trying to understand this stuff, since they have code that demonstrates pretty much everything. Here's the page that's relevant to you: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/adding-multiplayer-shooting?playlist=29690

Comment: In that example, they're clearly calling Instantiate() and Spawn() in a server function. I think that's probably the core of your problem--you're instantiating and spawning as the client.

Comment: It works - Thanks! This tutorial looks great, thanks very much for the link :)

Comment: Although the issue mainly laid in accidentally referencing the wrong script...